# JSON in MySQL : get data from an object within a range of keys

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-json, mariadb-10.4

#### What I have:

- A `mysql` table, say `table1`
- `table1` contains two columns viz. `id` and `data`
- `id` is `int` but the twist is `data` is `JSON` type and *its keys are comparable*
- the `table1` contains ***only one row*** *(for the sake of this question)*

**table1**

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {'1': 'content1', '2': 'content2', '3':'content3',.......,'10000':'content10000' } |

#### What I want to have:

I want a query such that it returns me key-value pairs within a range of keys, say, 100 to 200.

#### What I'm getting on searching on internet:

Everywhere I got only the answers where one can get rows which have the values within a range, but here the case is I want values of keys within a range.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you store the data as a JSON object if you wanted to query ranges of keys? Why not store it in another table, with two normal columns, `id` and `content`? Then you could query rows `WHERE id BETWEEN 100 AND 200` in a conventional way.

Comment: @BillKarwin I like your question, the reason of doing this is each row in the table has a json object with almost 1K to 1M key-value pairs. And we will be having almost 1M to 10M such rows, so maintaining them will be tedious. Also our requirements restrict us to use only one table. hope this fulfils your curiosity

Comment: Okay, well I don't know of any way to do the query you want with a JSON object. You could do it with [JSON_TABLE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html) if you used a JSON array instead (assuming you are using MySQL 8.0).

Comment: "Requirements restrict us to use only one table" is ridiculous for a relational database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I start with this data:

```
MariaDB [test]> select * from table1;
+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id   | data                                                                      |
+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | {"1": "content1", "2": "content2", "3":"content3","10000":"content10000"} |
+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE data AS (
  SELECT 
     JSON_VALUE(JSON_KEYS(data), '$[0]') AS k, 
     JSON_EXTRACT(data, CONCAT('$.',JSON_VALUE(JSON_KEYS(data), '$[0]'))) AS v, 
     0 AS idx 
  FROM table1
  UNION
  SELECT 
     JSON_VALUE(JSON_KEYS(data), CONCAT('$[', d.idx + 1, ']')) AS k, 
     JSON_EXTRACT(data, CONCAT('$.',JSON_VALUE(JSON_KEYS(data), CONCAT('$[', d.idx + 1, ']')))) AS v, 
     d.idx + 1 AS idx 
  FROM data AS d, table1
  WHERE d.idx < JSON_LENGTH(JSON_KEYS(data)) - 1
) SELECT * FROM data;
```

sample output (because if only have limited data):

```
+-------+----------------+------+
| k     | v              | idx  |
+-------+----------------+------+
| 1     | "content1"     |    0 |
| 2     | "content2"     |    1 |
| 3     | "content3"     |    2 |
| 10000 | "content10000" |    3 |
+-------+----------------+------+
```

Adding a WHERE-clause should not be a problem.

Comment: Well done, but the complex solutions required to work with JSON should convince anyone that it's better to use normal rows and columns.